# Do I need any financial certificate for my in-app wallet?

Tags: paypal, payment, mobile-application, wallet

I am currently developing a mobile application in which I am implementing a wallet feature and I am using the PayPal API.
The users can execute a service in exchange of a payment.
Is it possible to let the users store the money received in the wallet within the app ?
Will I also need to acquire any financial certificate before releasing the app?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask a lawyer or financial expert of the country(s) your business is based in as well as review any particular App Store policies, but my answer would be that with what you describe the "money received in the wallet" is more like "credits" until your app pays it out to an actual financial system.

You can use PayPal's [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts) to send money to an email address.

(If there's no PayPal account at that address the recipient will get a notification and have 30 days to create one or add this email to an existing account, otherwise a refunded is processed automatically)